# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo una vez modificado?

Tags: php

Necesito conocer la antigüedad de un archivo, por lo que estuve mirando en PHP y solo pude obtener la fecha de la última modificación.

Estuve probando las siguiente funciones:

- [`fileatime()`](https://php.net/es/fileatime)
- [`filemtime()`](https://php.net/es/filemtime)
- [`fstat()`](https://php.net/es/fstat)

¿Conocen alguna forma de obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo?

Comment: Existe la función **[`filectime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filectime.php)**. Lee las notas del Manual, si estás en un sistema Unix. En el enlace podrás experimentar con los ejemplos de código propuestos.

Comment: @A.Cedano , esa función devuelve la fecha de la última modificación (*change time*) del archivo y no de la creación. Siguiendo la nomenclatura usada en POSIX, la fecha de creación se denotaría por [`btime/birthtime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/File-timestamps.html), proviene de fecha de nacimiento (*birth time*).

Answer (score 3):

Por desgracia el soporte para el valor `btime` (*birth time* o fecha de creación/nacimiento) no está implementado aún en PHP (al menos hasta la versión 7.3), por lo que necesitarás la ayuda de un programa externo para comprobar dicho valor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>

/* Puedes borrar esta función si usas glibc 2.28 o superior */
ssize_t statx(int dfd, const char *filename, unsigned flags,
          unsigned int mask, struct statx *buffer)
{
    return syscall(__NR_statx, dfd, filename, flags, mask, buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct statx stx;
    int ret;

    /* Iteramos por cada archivo proporcionado por parámetro */
    for (argv++; *argv; argv++) {
        /* Realizamos la llamada al sistema */
        ret = statx(AT_FDCWD, *argv, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW, STATX_ALL, &stx);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror(*argv);
            return 1;
        }
        /* Mostramos la marca de tiempo junto con los microsegundos */
        printf("%llu.%09u\n", stx.stx_btime.tv_sec, stx.stx_btime.tv_nsec);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ahora deberemos compilar la aplicación usando:

```
gcc -o btime -Wall btime.c
```

Podemos copiar el archivo ejecutable generado `btime` a algún directorio del path (como `/usr/local/bin/`) o bien dejarlo en el directorio de trabajo del PHP que vamos a generar:

```
<?php
function filebtime($archivo) {
    $ret = 0;
    $btime = [];
    exec('./btime ' . escapeshellarg($archivo) . ' 2>&1', $btime, $ret);
    /* Si falló el programa externo o no devolvió datos devolvemos -1 */
    return (($ret !== 0) || (count($btime) === 0)) ? -1 : floatval($btime[0]);
}
echo filebtime('prueba'), PHP_EOL;
```

Ejemplo con un archivo de prueba:

```
$ touch prueba
$ php stat.php
1573199555.1128333
$ stat prueba
  Fichero: prueba
  Tamaño: 5             Bloques: 8          Bloque E/S: 4096   fichero regular
Dispositivo: fd00h/64768d   Nodo-i: 1049176     Enlaces: 1
Acceso: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ redstar)   Gid: ( 1000/ redstar)
Acceso: 2019-11-08 08:23:29.421929356 +0100
Modificación: 2019-11-08 08:23:29.421929356 +0100
      Cambio: 2019-11-08 08:23:29.421929356 +0100
    Creación: -
$ touch prueba
$ stat prueba
  Fichero: prueba
  Tamaño: 5             Bloques: 8          Bloque E/S: 4096   fichero regular
Dispositivo: fd00h/64768d   Nodo-i: 1049176     Enlaces: 1
Acceso: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ redstar)   Gid: ( 1000/ redstar)
Acceso: 2019-11-08 09:21:35.499843986 +0100
Modificación: 2019-11-08 09:21:35.499843986 +0100
      Cambio: 2019-11-08 09:21:35.499843986 +0100
    Creación: -
$ php stat.php
1573199555.1128333
```

PD1: La función `statx()` fue agregada en [**glibc 2.28**](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html) apoyándose en la llamada al sistema si está disponible o a través de `fstatat64()` en caso contrario. Si tu sistema operativo usa una versión reciente de glibc puedes borrar la definición de la función (ver comentario en el código).

PD2: La llamada del sistema `statx` fue agregada en la versión del núcleo de [**Linux 4.11**](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11#statx.282.29.2C_a_modern_stat.282.29_alternative), por lo que si el núcleo de tu sistema operativo es muy antiguo es posible que el código no funcione si no usas la implementación de `statx` de una versión de *glibc* reciente.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez te sea útil la alternativa de [`DirectoryIterator::getCTime()`](https://php.net/es/directoryiterator.getctime), la cual te devolvería la fecha en que los ficheros fueron subidos a un directorio.

Quedaría algo como esto:

```
<?php
    $recorrido = new DirectoryIterator(dirname('__FILE__'));
    foreach ($recorrido as $informacion) {
        if ($informacion->isFile()) {
            echo $informacion->getFilename(), " almacenado en ",
               date("F d Y H:i:s.", $informacion->getCTime()), "<br>", PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por desgracia [`DirectoryIterator::getCTime()`](https://php.net/es/directoryiterator.getctime) devuelve la fecha de la última modificación (*Change Time*), no la de creación (que es lo que pide el OP): ***Valores devueltos:** Devuelve el último cambio de tiempo de el fichero, en formato Unix timestamp*.

Comment: Por cierto, deberás usar la constante predefinida `__FILE__` y no la cadena de caracteres `'__FILE__'` o bien la constante `__DIR__` de forma directa, sin hacer uso de `dirname()` (siempre que tu versión de PHP está al día: se agregó en PHP 5.3 y la versión más antigua en mantenimiento es la 7.0).